# Access objects in custom UITableViewCells with same tag?

Tags: ios, arrays, tableview, nsindexpath

In my app, I use custom UITableViewCells loaded from a XIB. Each cell contains 4 objects, like a UIImageView, UILabel, UITextField, etc...

I set the tag of each object in my cellforrowatindexpath so each object has the same tag which also is the row of the cell in the tableview.

The problem is, how am I suppose to access these objects in a cell if they all have the same tag? How would I properly access these objects in a method that doesn't have a NSIndexPath parameter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally try avoiding the use of tags as I usually overuse them to the point of utter confusion and have begun finding more elegant ways around it. For instance, in your situation I would create `IBOutlet`s for the custom `UITableViewCell`'s objects making them more semantically relevant. However, your situation might be different - there is not enough in the question for me to say this would definitely work for you.

That said, it sounds like you could accomplish what you're trying to do by:

1. Giving each cell returned by the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method a tag (before returning it)
2. Giving each of the objects within the cell a tag, as you seem to have already done

That way you can access the cell's objects (presumably `UIView`s) from (anywhere) in your `UITableViewController` by:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self.tableview viewWithTag:CELL_TAG];
UIView *objectInCell = [cell viewWithTag:OBJECT_TAG];
```

Keep in mind that this would allow you to access an object in a **specific** cell. If you were trying to access the objects of **all** your cells, you could simply iterate through all of them. However, I sense that  this would start becoming unnecessarily complicated at this point. It would help if you posted up a bit more information on what exactly you were trying to achieve by utilising the tagging this way. Hope this helps in the meantime.

Comment: Yes most of what you said is right but lets say in one cell I have 4 objects with the tag of 3 is it possible to just get the object by casting the type before I do viewWithTag (they are all different objects).

Comment: That doesn't sound possible, since you will only ever retrieve a single `UIView` with the `viewWithTag` method. I haven't tried this out myself, but based on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978720/what-uiview-is-returned-when-using-viewwithtag-when-several-views-have-same-t), it seems that you will get the view you added first (with the tag 3). You can check the type with `isKindOfClass`, but you won't be able to access the other 3 objects. So in a nutshell, no, it's not possible. You should only use tags to specifically refer to a single other `UIView`.

Comment: Pretty much in the end I want to give EACH object in EACH row a unique tag so I can access it easily. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: I'm beginning to understand what you're trying to achieve. Assuming you're trying to access these objects (essentially `UIView`s of the `UITableViewCell`) from the `UITableViewController`, it would not matter if each object in each row has a unique tag, because they will still only be accessed within the scope of the `UITableViewCell` itself. Going back to my initial answer, you would first need to get a reference to the `UITableViewCell` that has the object you're looking for and then call another `viewWithTag` on that to retrieve the specific object.

Comment: In other words, you will still not be able to do a `[tableView viewWithTag:objectTag]` as the `objectTag` is only understood (and valid) when you call `[cell viewWithTag:objectTag]`. So you will only be able to do a `[tableView viewWithTag:cellTag]`, unless you subview the `cell` objects directly under the `tableView` - which then makes using a `UITableView` redundant in this case.

Comment: So your saying that these objects can have the same tag but as long as they are in different UITableViewCells, correct?

Comment: Also since my UITableViewCells are custom I would do [myCell viewWithTag:objectTag]; etc.. Would that work?

Comment: Yes - you could give them all unique tags, but it would not matter as they're only 'defined' within the scope of the `UITableViewCell` that they are subview'd under.

Comment: Yes it would. `[myCell viewWithTag:objectTag]` would work. May I ask why you unaccepted my answer after I had elaborated it further?

Comment: Sorry, re-accepted. So bottom line here, set tags 1-4 on each object in my cells. Then I would just get the certain cell I need, then just access it with numbers 1-4 right?

Comment: Yup, that's right. However, going back to your initial question (where you specified that you want to do this in a method that doesn't have the `NSIndexPath` parameter available) - you will still need to know the `tag` or `rowIndex` of the cell to be able to get it.

Comment: Hmm thats where it gets complicated. The thing is though, I cannot get the index path easily because the user is actually not tapping on the cell but instead on a UITextField so I am not sure which UITextField it is, what should be my logistic in this scenario?

Comment: Well, assuming the `UITextField` is one of those 4 objects in each cell, you can get a reference to your `MyCell` object with `MyCell *myCell = (MyCell *)[textField superView]`. Then, you could either get another object in that cell with `[myCell viewWithTag:objectTag]`, or (if you need it) determine the `NSIndexPath` with `[tableView indexPathForCell:myCell]`.

Comment: Thanks! You have helped me out so much!

Answer (score 0):

No idea why one would number all the tags in a row with the same number, but I suppose you have your reasons ([cell1 viewwithTag:0] and [cell2 viewWithTag: 0] should be more than enough to differentiate them.)

Giving all the elements the same tag generally defeats the purpose of tagging them in the first place, though if you MUST include the row number in the tag (and have some idea about the size of the result set), you could tag each element with a ((multiple of size) + item# ) integer (e.g., if you know the table will hold fewer than 10,0000 results, you could tag each element as 10001, 10002, 10003 and 10004 in the first row, and 20001, 20002, 20003 and 20004 in the next, etc... Then to address the third element in the 4th row, you would use [view withTag: 40003].

Comment: Im just wondering the best way to differentiate the objects in a cell row. What do you think?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. If each object in a row has its own unique number 0 to 3 (instead of giving them all the same number), differentiating them with viewWithTag: should not be an issue. Why exactly are you assigning all the views the same tag?

Comment: The problem is actually setting the values to different values so that I can access ALL the objects in the cell. I could just do tag 1000 etc... But I would rather not, is there any clear way to do it?

Comment: How are you setting the tags currently -- through code? Or through IB? I'm just unclear as to why you're setting them all the same in the first place, when numbering them 1 through 4 should allow you to access each within the scope of the parent cell. I.e., why are you using the row number as a tag at all?

Comment: Through code. I am not sure how to set them all differently in each row. I am using row number currently but it seems that, that is not the right way to do it. Can you show me how to give each object in each cell a unique number so I can access it easily?

Answer (score -1):

You can access the row of the selected cell with this methode:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]
```

but i am not sure if this answers your question. Please be more concrete.

Comment: person is asking about tags inside a tableviewcell, not how to figure out which cell is at an index